# How to re-throw error after blocking call in Java Reactor?

Tags: java, project-reactor

When I call `.block()` in Java Reactor if there was an error it throws `ReactiveException`. I need to get the source exception that is wrapped into `ReactiveException` and re-throw it.

This code works but it there any better way to achieve the goal?

```java
try {
    return myService.getObject(.....).block();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e.getCause() != null ? e.getCause() : e;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Exceptions.unwrap(e)`

For example:

```
import reactor.core.Exceptions;

...

try {
    return myService.getObject(.....).block();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw Exceptions.unwrap(e);
}
```

Comment: Note that this way you risk losing current stack trace because Reactor pipelines usually run on there own thread pools. Consider wrapping it again to your own exception.